# Не получается заинфлейтить View из xml

Tags: java, android, android-customview

Есть `CustomView` (эта View является внутренным классом в MainActivity.), хочу ее заинфлейтить через `xml`, но получаю ошибку.

Ниже привожу код `View`:

```
public class RecordButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartRecording = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onRecord(mStartRecording);

                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                android.util.Log.i("Time Current ", " Time value in millisecinds " + start);

                if (mStartRecording) {
                    setText("Stop recording");
                } else {
                    setText("Start recording");
                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
            }
        };

        public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start recording");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<resources>
        <declare-styleable name="com.example.AudioRecordTest.RecordButton">
            <attr name="labelPosition" format="enum">
                <enum name="left" value="0"/>
                <enum name="right" value="1"/>
            </attr>
        </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
//some code

 <com.example.AudioRecordTest.RecordButton
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="78dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|fill_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Test1" />
```

Собственно ошибка:

```
 `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class com.example.AudioRecordTest.RecordButton`
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.AudioRecordTest.RecordButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Внутренний класс должен быть статическим. Со всеми вытекающими: невозможностью обращаться к не статическим методам и переменным объекта MainActivity...

   ```
   public static class RecordButton extends Button {...}
   ```
2. В разметке обращаться тогда к нему так:

   ```
   <view class="com.example.AudioRecordTest$RecordButton"
       android:id="@+id/test1"
       android:layout_width="78dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_column="1"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|fill_vertical"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:text="Test1"/>
   ```

N.B. `view` - именно в нижнем регистре.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098318/error-referencing-an-inner-class-view-in-layout-main-xml

ЗЫ Лучше его сделать внешним классом и работать как обычно.